# Can't get the "s" flag to work in regex in Saxon 9.5

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have an XML envelope/payload structure like this:

```
<RootEnvelopeTag>
    <EnvelopeTag />
    <EnvelopeTag />
    <EnvelopeTagContainingPayload>
        &lt;WantedPayloadTag&gt;Some text and nested tags.&lt;/WantedPayloadTag&gt;&lt;UnwantedPayloadTag&gt;Lots of text and nested tags.&lt;/UnwantedPayloadTag&gt;
    </EnvelopeTagContainingPayload>
</RootEnvelopeTag>
```

To extract the payload, by removing all envelope elements, I use the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/EnvelopeTagContainingPayload"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="EnvelopeTagContainingPayload">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The result is a new text file that, once parsed as XML, allows me to work only with the payload XML.

This works fine in both Saxon HE 9.5, and AltovaXML 2013. However, I am now in the need to also remove part of the payload, specifically, one element, including the tags and all of its content (the <UnwantedPayloadTag>ALL TEXT IN BETWEEN</UnwantedPayloadTag>).

Since, in the original XML file, the payload is just a string, I use replace() with a regular expression that matches the unwanted element and the empty string as replacement string. I include the "s" flag, to get the "." in the regex to match newlines present within the unwanted element. So, the template for the container envelope element changes to:

```
  <xsl:template match="EnvelopeTagContainingPayload">
    <xsl:variable name="removeUnwanted" as="xs:string" select="replace(., '&lt;UnwantedPayloadTag.*UnwantedPayloadTag&gt;', '', 's')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$removeUnwanted"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

In AltovaXML, this works seamlessly. The result is exactly as expected. But in Saxon, it wreaks havoc. No output is generated; instead, I get in the command line an endless repetition of the following error message that clutters the whole DOS command line window:

at net.sf.saxon.regex.Operation$OpStar.exec(Operation.java:235)

at net.sf.saxon.regex.REMatcher.matchNodes(REMatcher.java:413)

The problem appears only when I use the "s" flag. But if I drop it, I won't get the match. I tried an alternative that doesn't require the flag and does the same:

```
    <xsl:variable name="removeUnwanted" as="xs:string" select="replace(., '&lt;UnwantedPayloadTag[\s\S]*UnwantedPayloadTag&gt;', '')" />
```

But I get the same error on Saxon. And again, Altova gets it right. I'm unsure of whether the problem is on my code, since it works fine in Altova. But I would really like to get this to work in Saxon, as well. So, what's wrong?

Comment: That clutter of messages is usually a stack trace that helps identify where a Java application failed exactly so consider to provide the full stack trace. It is best to provide minimal but complete samples of XML and XSLT allowing to reproduce the error. The quickest resolution also would be posting on the Saxon mailing list or support forum.

Comment: @Martin: The problem with the full stack trace is that it keeps repeating, as far as I can see. It's always an alternation of the two lines above. Nothing else. So, it wouldn't be much of help if I reproduced tens of lines of the same. Also, it spans beyond the cache of lines that is retained in the DOS command line window. So, my original call to the transformation, along with the initial lines of the repeating message are lost. If I scroll the window all the way up, the only thing I can see are those two lines of error messages.

Comment: I would be glad to provide a sample of the full XML I'm using. Didn't do it here because It is too big for this venue. Is this the appropriate place to do so: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/saxon-help ?

Comment: If you want to raise support queries with saxonica, the preferred route is http;//saxonica.plan.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saxon 9.6 is now available and even the Home Edition HE supports XPath 3.0 functions like parse-xml-fragment the right approach to your problem is now doing

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/EnvelopeTagContainingPayload"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EnvelopeTagContainingPayload">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UnwantedPayloadTag"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

as that way you simply parse the markup as XML and then use templates to filter out any elements you don't want.

Comment: Martin, yours is by far the best approach. First, it is more efficient (no backtracking strain on the processor). Second, it spares me from having to use an XML pipeline. Now, the parsed XML is readily available for any further processing. It is great news that SaxonHE 9.6 supports XPath 3.0 functions. This makes way easier to handle nested XMLs payloads. Thank you for your generous suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a stack overflow in the Saxon regular expression engine because there's too much backtracking. We've got a fix for that in the future 9.6 release, but in the meantime you need to be careful about regular expressions that do too much backtracking.

Really, your approach is wrong. Regular expressions should not be used to parse XML. Your expression is wrong, because it can match things that it shouldn't match, e.g. something in a comment that looks like an end tag. You can't get it right by tweaking the regex, because XML has a recursive grammar and regular expressions can't handle recursive grammars. Saxon provides parse-xml() for this purpose.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you, Michael. The best approach is to parse the payload using fn:parse-xml() or saxon:parse(). However, neither XSLT 3.0 features, nor extension functions are available in SaxonHE. So, I was left only with the primitive regular expressions alternative. That led me to my stack overflow (quite appropriately :) ). Anyway, it's good to know that Saxon 9.6 will fix the backtracking issue (may I know when?). It does no harm to have a stronger regex engine built in Saxon. Thanks for your feedback!